# How to color comments after a defined column

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, highlight

I once was given these materials to enable this helper for `vim` to show kind of a vertical line in order to help enforce PEP8 rules on line length limit at column 80:

```
"   Long lines highlighting.
nnoremap <Leader>H :call<SID>LongLineHLToggle()<cr>
hi OverLength ctermbg=none cterm=none
match OverLength /\%>80v/
fun! s:LongLineHLToggle()
    if !&diff
        if !exists('w:longlinehl')
            let w:longlinehl = matchadd('ErrorMsg', '.\%>80v', 0)
            echo "Long lines highlighted"
        else
            call matchdelete(w:longlinehl)
            unl w:longlinehl
            echo "Long lines unhighlighted"
        endif
    endif
endfunction
```

In action:

[image: long line highlighter toggler in action]

I use all of this for marking the 80th column.

Given enough time and effort I very much could have a similar facility in `vim` for marking text far beyond column 72 **only when in comment.** I guess it has been already coded by somebody somewhere at some point. **Do you already know where to find that snippet?**

Comment: You can find out if something is highlighted as a comment with `synID()` and `synIDattr()`. Something like:  `if ((synIDattr(synID(line("."), 72, 0), "name") =~ 'comment\c')`

Comment: Am I supposed to link that to a `nnoremap` or `autocmd` or something? Writing that to the `:` console threw `E110` and `E15` .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try a contained syntax region:

```
syn match TooLong contained containedin=pythonComment /\%50c.*/
hi link TooLong Error
```

Instead of `50`, use `80` or `72` or whichever column you prefer.

[image]

Comment: Which `vim` version is that?

Comment: 8.0.586, using molokai as the colorscheme.

Comment: Like `vim --version` presenting `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0.586 ...`? Am not sure of what am doing, but I think is not working for me as yours. Mine is telling `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Mar 10 2017 00:54:29) ...`, that is the vanilla VIM of Debian Jessie.

Comment: There's nothing particularly new in this, all features I'm using here are pretty old, and should work with Jessie's 7.4.488 (because this works on CentOS 7's Vim 7.4.160 as well). Say, did you test this in a Python file? Since you mentioned PEP8, I used the `containedin=pythonComment`. If you're using some other filetype, you'll have to look up what the syntax region for comments is and use that instead.

Comment: Tried appending that to my all time .vimrc, open Python source with long comments, I see no change. Tried opening the same source with a one time .vimrc with just `syntax on` and the two lines you hint, I see no change either. But after Python is working I will want that to work for any document the syntax highlighting of Vim can highlight (not worried by per language configuration for now).

Comment: @uprego Run those commands after you open a Python file. Simply adding those lines to a `vimrc` won't work, since syntax files loaded later would likely clear any current rules. Use an autocmd or `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim`.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561905/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561905/) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611888/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611888/)